# Irregular Array With Cell Borders

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics

I'm looking for advice about how to use tikz (or something else) to create images like the following (ignore the sloppy undeleted top border) in a beamer presentation.  I will need to fill various locations with x's during the presentation, label the columns and ideally change the color of certain cell borders to highlight say the 5x3 part of a 8x3 array.  So far the various solutions I've found here for drawing cell boundaries require I pick a certain column height and then draw a border all the way up to the top.

So what I'll need to do during the presentation is things like "draw a red/black x in cell 5,3" (or any other mark really), "highlight the border of the subtable with dimensions 5x3 in red"  I don't need to put data in the cells.

Any suggestions as to the best packages/approaches would be most helpful.  I was going to try to the matrix library from tikz but I saw several suggestions here that it was easier to use some non-tikz based solution for somewhat similar things but I couldn't find any that would let me have irregular borders like this for an array either in the matrix library or in the other methods I saw.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please, give the code of your unsuccessful trial.

Comment: `tikz` is certainly a good choice, but the approach depends on what data you want to represent and how you want to input it, etc. I mean, at this point your question is a bit vague.

Comment: Ok, I'll add the info about what i want to be able to input and represent.

Comment: @AndréC I don't know how to draw irregular cell borders in tikz (or indeed any package) without just drawing a bunch of boxes by hand.  I just mocked that up in a drawing program quickly to communicate the effect I'm trying to produce.  I'm hoping to be pointed to the best package to do this kind of thing so I don't reinvent the wheel if I don't have to.  I don't need specific code…I'm just looking to know what I should use to approach this before I start coding it.

Comment: You could take a look at the `nicematrix` package. With it you should be able to produce such images. I just have not tries to use it in combination with beamer overlays.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks...I'll post that as an answer so others can see it unless you want to do thst!.

Answer (score 1):

@leandris has suggested I use the [nicematrix](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix?lang=en) package to this end.  Based on a prelimimary look at the package it seems perfect (looks like I can use hvlines-except-corners with some phantom elements to get the desired effect quite easily).

Comment: This is better added as a comment to your question, which you should be able to add yourself.